# What is difference between these two linq queries?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

There are two linq querys in below, they return complete difference result, first query return 4 records second return 72 records. I think they are same. Who can explain why they return difference record set. Thanks for helping.

```
void Main()
{
    var q1 = from c in Customers
            where !c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderDetails.Sum(od => od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) < 1000)
            select new {c.CustomerID, c.ContactName};

    q1.Dump();

    var q2 = from c in Customers
             where c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderDetails.Sum(od => od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice) >= 1000)
             select new {c.CustomerID, c.ContactName};

    q2.Dump();
}
```

Comment: maybe easier to understand : `!Any()` is the same as `All()`

Comment: The difference may be in how the database evaluates NULLs, but not confident enough yet in what's going on to list this as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The first returns customers that **do not have** any orders whose total price is **less than** 1000.
2. The second returns customers that **have** any orders whose total price is **greater than or equal** to 1000.

In other words, imagine a customer who made one order of total price less than 1000, and another order of total price greater than 1000. Because of the smaller order, the customer record **would not** be included in the first result set, but because of the larger order, it **would** be included in the second result set.